Prove that $F(x,y) = f(x) - f(y)$ for Lebesgue measurable $f$ on $[0,1]$ and $F \in L^{1}([0,1]\times [0,1])$ implies $f \in L^{1}([0,1])$.
I am having trouble with an exercise within the book "Modern Real Analysis" by Ziemer.
The exercise appears in chapter 6 (on integration) within section 6.8 on the dual space of $L^{p}$. The exercise statement is :

Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $[0,1]$ and $Q := [0,1] \times [0,1]$.
a.) Show that $F(x,y) := f(x) - f(y)$ is measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure
in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
b.) If $F \in L^{1}(Q)$, show that $f \in L^{1}([0,1])$.

Here I assume the shared co-domain of $f$ and $F$ is the extended real numbers $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. The measurable space defined on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is
$(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$ with
$\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ denoting the Borel sets. $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ or $Q$ depending on the context.
My solution so far is below :
a.) Let :
\begin{align*}
F_{1}(x,y) & = f(x) \\
F_{2}(x,y) & = f(y)
\end{align*}
So $F = F_{1} - F_{2}$. Since sums of measurable functions are measurable and the measurability of a function is not changed when it is multiplied by $g \equiv -1$ :
\begin{equation*}
F_{1} \text{ and } F_{2} \text{ are } \lambda\text{-measurable} \Rightarrow F \text{ is } \lambda\text{-measurable}
\end{equation*}
Let $D \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. We see :
\begin{equation*}
F_{1}^{-1}(D) = f^{-1}(D) \times [0,1]
\end{equation*}
where $f^{-1}(D)$ and $[0,1]$ are $\lambda$-measurable. According to ( Is the product of two measurable subsets of $R^d$ measurable in $R^{2d}$?)
$f^{-1}(D) \times [0,1]$ is also $\lambda$-measurable. So $F_{1}^{-1}(D)$ is measurable.  Can use the same argument for $F_{2}$ so that $F$ is $\lambda$-measurable.
I still haven't been able to find a good approach for solving part (b.). Can someone help with this ?

Tonelli’s theorem is a good place to start (and recall that if $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(X)>0$ and $\phi:X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, then $\int_X\phi,d\mu<\infty$ implies $\phi$ is a.e finite-valued, in particular there exists $x\in X$ such that $\phi(x)<\infty$).

For $N\in \mathbb{N}$ set $E_N={ x\in [0,1] \ : \ \vert f(x)\vert \geq N}$. Find $N$ such that $\lambda(E_{2N})> \lambda(E_N)>0$. Then we have $$\int_{[0,1]} \vert f \vert \leq 2N+\int_{E_{2N}} \vert f\vert.$$ On the other hand, we have $$ \int_Q \vert F \vert \geq \int_{E_{2N} \times ([0,1]\setminus E_N)} \vert F \vert \geq \lambda([0,1]\setminus E_N)\int_{E_{2N}} \vert f \vert - \int_{[0,1]\setminus E_N} \vert f \vert \geq \lambda([0,1]\setminus E_N)\int_{E_{2N}} \vert f \vert -N.$$

It looks like $|f(x)| \geq N$ should be $|f(x)| \leq N$.
